# upload large files in a browser with a progress bar, prefer no flash just js and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, progress-bar

what is the best way to build an upload widget that can handle large files

is there a great jquery plugin for this?

I'd really love to have a progress bar without having to depend on flash

would need to use php for the backend

Comment: There are *lots* of answered questions almost exactly like this.

Comment: As Pointy said, you are not the first to ask the question. And AFAIK, there is no practical way to do that (with progress bar) in pure JS, that would suppose JS is accessing a file by chunks.
If I am wrong, I would be glad to be corrected and pointed to a resource.

Comment: he's not asking for pure JS. "js and php" ... "would need to use php for the backend"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done without patching PHP or using a combination of PHP and (perl or something else).

See:
http://pdoru.from.ro/
and
http://www.raditha.com/php/progress.php

Comment: http://evox.ro/upload-progress-meter/ says "This is a very old project which is no longer maintained."

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/).

Comment: It needs one of Flash, Silverlight, Gears, BrowserPlus or HTML5 support... So it is still not "pure JS" (except perhaps for HTML5, but it isn't so much widespread - yet).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

Comment: ... except he said explicitly that he doesn't want Flash!

Comment: My apologies - I was under the mistaken impression that uploadify was pure jQuery/javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Blue Imp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload#readme)!  Very nice interface and jQuery branch too!

Answer (score 0):

APC allows to monitor file uploads from PHP http://www.phpriot.com/articles/php-ajax-file-uploads

Answer (score 0):

You can code by yourselve the script that handles large uploads. You need html5 to slice in pieces the file and then upload them, and implode all the parts in the php server.
I have write how to do that in my blog
http://apuntes.alexmoleiro.com/2013/07/subir-archivos-grandes-de-100-mb-hasta.html
It is spanish but the you are going to understand everything just reading the code.
Hope it will be useful for you and for everyone that wants to upload big files without using widgets that really don't do exactly what we want.